# Data transfer through wifi (without internet) between PC and Laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, file-transfer

What is the easiest way to transfer data without internet through WiFi.
I have

- a WiFi router.
- Windows XP SP3 PC
- Windows 7 Laptop.

Comment: Some people talk about Wifi-Direct. Seems to work on windows.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a USB flash drive or external hard drive PC Transfer Software. Here you can check https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/transfer-files-from-pc-to-pc-without-internet.html how to transfer files from PC to PC without internet on Windows 11/10/8/7

Answer (score 7):

- Connect both computers to the same WiFi router.
- Enable File and Printer Sharing on both computers.  If you right click on a file or folder from either computer and choose to Share it, you will be prompted to turn on File and Printer Sharing.  So, doing this to both the Shared Documents (all users) on the Windows XP machine, and the Public Documents (on the Windows 7 machine) would be a way to go.  Microsoft provides [a detailed explanation here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows).
- View the Available Network computers from either computer.  Then, copy and paste the data you want to transfer.  *For example*... if you have a song sitting on the Windows XP Machine in what is now the Shared Music directory, you would browse to that computer in the Network Connections available in Explorer on the Windows 7 machine, browse to that folder, select the song, copy it, and then paste it wherever you wanted it to be on the Windows 7 machine.

You don't need to install third party software.  Everything you need to transfer files and folders between your computers is already included.

Now, if you meant something ELSE by your use of the phrase "transfer data" you will need to detail that.

Comment: This is the best solution, you should not need third party software, I would go with this answer OP

Answer (score 2):

I have [IPMessenger](http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en) installed in my system. This helps me in file transfer from my laptop to my desktop and vice-versa through the wifi router. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Between the same two computers, Lan messenger, Beebeep gave me 400 KBps, while windows file sharing gave < 100 KBps. IP Messenger gave me 20 MBps transfer speed. The interface was also cleanest. install was quickest.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a website on your local machine and create a folder where you can keep your files to share. That solution will work with any device regardless installed OS. I use it to copy files to my mobile.

1. Create a website in IIS (e.g. on Win 7)
2. Enable Directory Browsing
3. Open admin panel in your router (typical 192.168.1.1) and setup port forwarding to machine with your website (the one with Win 7).

Now you can navigate to your website using your router IP and port (e.g. 192.168.1.1:8081)

[For step by step instruction go here](http://sitecorebond.com/archive/copying-data-to-your-mobile-over-wifi/)

Answer (score 1):

Visit Andro Root Here for more methods:- https://www.androroot.com/2017/10/how-to-share-big-files-between.html

**Steps to Send Big Files between windows Computers Without Internet:-**

1. Connect both computers either to the same network, to the same
   router or create a wireless hotspot on the first Laptop and connect
   the second laptop to the hotspot using following steps.
2. In windows xp, vista, & 7
   Click “Start” and select “Control Panel” on one computer.
   Click “View Network Status and Tasks” under Network and Internet.
3. In windows 8 & 10 
   Click “Start” and select "Settings"
   Click “View Network Status and Tasks” under Network and Internet.
4. Click “Set Up a New Connection or Network” under Change Your
5. Networking Settings. Select the “Manually connect to a wireless network in 
        windows 10 and ad-hoc in others” option and click “Next.”
6. Type a name for your wireless network into the “Network Name” box.
7. Select a security type such as“WPA2-Personal” from the “Security Type” box.
8. Type a password into the “Security Key” box.
9. You’ll need this to connect to the other PC.
10. Click the “Save This Network” checkbox and select “Next” to create the 
    network.
11. Click the “Network” icon in the second PC’s system
    tray,
12. Then select the network you created and provide its password
    to connect.
13. Launch the file explorer on first PC/Lappy.
14. Copy all files which you want to share in a separate folder
15. Right-click on the folder. Click on Properties. Click on Sharing Tab.
16. Click on Advanced sharing.
17. Now click on the box which is located just in front of Share this Folder 
    option.
18. Now check the permissions and all other options depend on your need.
19. Click on Apply and then on OK.

That's it.
Your files and folders will be available for other computers on
    the wireless network. And Your shared files and folders can be found
    under “Network” in the File Explorer on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

1.you need to do is find and get software called WIPEER.

2.install the program on your laptop wipeer. Install the program and place it on the operating system wipeer

3.after the installation wipeer successful then you can see the display wipeer program. Setting / set some program functions wipeer to be used properly. You need to consider in setting the program is on (SSID) that serves as an ad hoc peer 2 peer network name laptop. We recommend that you give the same name as the SSID, as if different p2p not be able to connect with another laptop.

4.if you have done the settings in the program wipeer correctly. Please check the connection to the wireless network connections on your laptop. Is the name of the SSID that you created has been in the network options (network) wifi. If the SSID name already exists and there are images p2p laptop (figure 2 laptops that are connected by wifi)

5.check the status of the connection to the wireless network connections. If you have connected (connection) then you can use wipeer program. You can bersharing data / chat / gaming etc as you like.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee best possible transmission speeds and reliability, I use an offline wifi method (tested on both Win. 7 and 10):

1. First download IP Messenger on both Windows computers (https://ipmsg.org/en).
2. Hook up a separate router that's not connected to the internet.
3. Connect both computers to the internet-less router.
4. Transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

[BeeBEEP](https://www.beebeep.net/) or [LAN Messenger](https://lanmessenger.github.io/) would be great choices to solve such a problem. Both being Open Source and available on both 3 main platforms (Linux, Windows, Mac)